# Experience Bundle deploy- The activeViewId for the XXX route in .../routes/reportBuilder.json doesn’t point to a valid view. Update activeViewId

Tags: deployment-error, experience-bundle

I'm deploying Experience Bundles from our PROD Customer Service/guest user-only site (called `Help_Center1` to our Staging sandbox which has gotten out of date with PROD

```
PROD -> VCS -> Staging
```

When deploying the Experience Bundle metadata, I get this error

```
The activeViewId for the Report Builder route in Help_Center1/routes/reportBuilder.json doesn’t point to 
a valid view. Update activeViewId to point to the default view of the route.
```

**/routes/reportBuilder.json** (in package)

```
{
  "activeViewId" : "50a9310f-19e5-45c4-9c22-54dbf783275c",  <= points at views id
  "appPageId" : "f53e924c-1d7d-466c-b680-0183617d4fec", <== matches the views appPageId
  "configurationTags" : [ ],
  "id" : "5f080c67-a94a-4919-8d76-8e825b4d9d02",
  "label" : "Report Builder",
  "routeType" : "createreport",
  "type" : "route",
  "urlPrefix" : "createreport"
}
```

**/views/reportBuilder.json** (in package)

```
{
  "appPageId" : "f53e924c-1d7d-466c-b680-0183617d4fec", <= matches the routes appPageId
  "componentName" : "siteforce:sldsOneColLayout",
  "dataProviders" : [ ],
  "id" : "50a9310f-19e5-45c4-9c22-54dbf783275c", <== matches the routes activeViewId
  "label" : "Report Builder",
  "regions" : [ ... ],
  "themeLayoutType" : "Inner",
  "type" : "view",
  "viewType" : "createreport"
}
```

You can see that the incoming package file for `routes/reportBuilder.json` point at the correct id for the `views/reportBuilder.json`.

I honestly don't know how to get around this. It is as if SFDC deploys the `/routes/xxx.json` file before realizing that it also has a new `views/xxx.json` that has the referenced ids.

Comment: Sounds like a support case is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this was user error

My deployment tool in this use case was Gearset that displays for selection each Experience Bundle folder/file as a separate row in their Difference Viewer

While I had included the `/routes/reportBuilder.json` file in the package, **I had omitted** the `/views/reportBuilder.json` file in the package (despite what the OP asserts)

Thus, the deployment of the `/routes/ReportBuilder.json` pointed at a view Id:

```
"50a9310f-19e5-45c4-9c22-54dbf783275c"
```

The target org still had the old `/view/ReportBuilder.json` `id` (e.g.

```
"50a8872f-91e6-45c4-8a23-66httydy7sld"
```

so a mismatch occurred.

I made a Product Enhancement suggestion to Gearset for adding a check (they call it the Analyzer) for this use case